# How to update an empty jsonb column using jsonb_set in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

My purpose is to update a `jsonb` column using `jsonb_set`, which is currently null, with an object having more than one key-value pairs. The update command executes successfully but it is not updating anything, the column is still coming up empty. I am trying the following query.

```
UPDATE tab 
  set value = jsonb_set(value, '{}', '{"a" : 100, "b" : [100, 200]}'::jsonb) 
where id = 100;
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: if `value` is null initially then use like this `coalesce(value,'[]'::jsonb)`.

Answer (score 5):

From what I've understood, it appears you don't need `jsonb_set` for this case. Simply cast the string to `jsonb` for updating

```
UPDATE tab 
  set value = '{"a" : 100, "b" : [100, 200]}'::jsonb
where id = 100 
--and value is null; --additional check if you need.
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3f4ee4a7e79d23a03393c3026550df64)

Comment: Yes, I know this way. But how to achieve the same if I want to do with jsonb_set only ? Or, what I'm asking is not possible at all ?

Comment: @ShaliniJ. : Most likely not possible and nothing that I know of using `jsonb_set` .`jsonb_set` works only on existing jsons, to set a particular value. You are actually adding a new json, so it should be either an insert or update.